# how to make a button get implicitly clicked when an hyperlink in the same page get clicked

Tags: jquery, html, button, hyperlink

I have for some reason a button and an hyperlink who must do the same action when the hyperlink get clicked the button need's to get clicked in the same time I think of using JQuery like so but I'm not sure this will work :

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Part of the HTML Code :

```
 <a href="" class="mission">
              <img src="images/mission.png" alt="" class="tooltipButton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Code Tricks">
            </a>
```

---

```
<button class="boutonCode effeckt-page-transition-button" data-effeckt-transition-in="scale-down-from-front" data-effeckt-transition-out="scale-down-to-behind" data-effeckt-transition-page="page-5" data-effeckt-needs-perspective="true">Code <i class="ion-arrow-right-c size-20"></i></button>
```

any other suggestions are welcome , Thank you

Comment: my html page contain too much code , here is the button and the hyperlink in the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$("a.mission").on("click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
  $("button.boutonCode").trigger("click");
});
```